# Automatically map columns to class properties with NHibernate ClassMapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm using setting up NHibernate 5.2 to try it on a local SQLExpress database.

My `Category` entity (by the way it's the sample [Northwind](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23654) database)

```cs
public class Category
{
    public virtual int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] Picture { get; set; }
}
```

My `CategoryMap`

```cs
public class CategoryMap : ClassMapping<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        Table("Categories");
        Id(x => x.CategoryID);
    }
}
```

My testing configurations and query

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Configuration config = new Configuration()
            .DataBaseIntegration(db =>
            {
                db.ConnectionString = @"<my connection string>";
                db.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
            });

        var mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.AddMappings(new List<Type> {
            typeof(CategoryMap)
        });;

        var mapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
        config.AddMapping(mapping);

        var sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();

        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            var categories = session.QueryOver<Category>().List<Category>();
        };

    }
}
```

However, I notice that in my test query, only the `CategoryID` field is populated, other fields are nulls (in database, table `Categories` they have values). If I add more `Property(x => x.<field name>)` to `CategoryMap`, they get their respective values as expected.
[image: My Categories table]

My question is: Do I have to manually add `Property(x => x.<property name here>` for every column in the table even though they have identical names with entity's properties ? Am I missing any configuration to make it automatically mapped ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong `ModelMapper`. I changed it to `ConventionModelMapper` and just need to specify the table name in class mapping.

My new `CategoryMap`

```cs
public class CategoryMap : ClassMapping<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        Tables("Categories");
        Id(x => x.CategoryID);
        // In db this column's type is image
        // while the property type is byte[] so this explicit property map is needed
        Property(x => x.Picture, m => m.Type(new BinaryBlobType()));
    }
}
```

Part of my config (in the same Program class, the rest are omitted for brevity)

```cs
...
// Unlike ModelMapper, this mapper automatically maps class name -> table, property -> column
var mapper = new ConventionModelMapper();
mapper.AddMapping<CategoryMap>();

var mapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
config.AddMapping(mapping);
...
```